# Office 365 - how to set working hours for all users

Tags: exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365, calendar

MS Office 365 has a default working hours set for all users for 8am to 5pm.

When working with the Office 365 API this setting limits the ability to see users free/busy time outside these hours.

How can we set the default working hours for all users or remove this limitation altogether?

Comment: hope [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-your-work-hours-and-days-in-Outlook-a27f261d-0681-415f-8ac1-388ab21e833f) should resolve your issue?

Comment: Thank @Corleone. This is for an individual user, my question was about changing the defaults for the organization, thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can connect to the [Exchange Online Management Shell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984289(v=exchg.160).aspx) and run the following script to achieve what you want, something like this perhaps (without knowing the working hours you want to configure):

```
Get-Mailbox | Where {$_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox"} | 
Set-MailboxCalendarConfiguration -WorkingHoursStartTime 00:00:00 -WorkingHoursEndTime 00:00:00 -ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours $false
```

The `-ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours $false` flag will allow for weekend scheduling.